# Pass multiple parameters from stored procedure to crystal reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I have written the following stored procedure to return two parameters (fields), whenever it is executed in Management Studio, the result of both select statements are shown. However, when connected via Crystakl Reports, only the first parameter (i.e Counted) is shown.

```
USE [database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT count(ID)as Counted from tab where Stat='1' 
    SELECT count(ID)as Counted2 from tab where Stat='2'
END
```

Comment: combine both COUNTs into one query in two columns instead of TWO result sets; SSMS is different to applications;

Comment: How do I combine the where clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SELECT query to include both outputs

```
SELECT sum(case when Stat='1' then 1 else 0 end) as Counted, 
       sum(case when Stat='2' then 1 else 0 end) as Counted2 
from dbo.Batch
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly